# Input type number decimal not accepting in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

```css
input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
}

.no-spin::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.no-spin::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" lang="en">
```

I am unable to get Firefox 60.0.2 to accept period `(.)` to enter decimal number. But the same is working in chrome. This does not work even with style removed.

How to write proper html input tag with either text or number type but preferably number type so decimal input is accepted

Comment: Why not just use `type=text`?

Comment: change the `oninput` code to `console.log(this.value);` ... and you'll see the problem straight away

Comment: Your input handler regex is messing this up - once that is removed, inputting a `.` is no problem in Firefox.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I see that regex is messing it up, can you elaborate why the regex is not sufficiently meaningful or why exactly is regex breaking, because the same seems to work with text field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use type=text, as you already have script to allow only decimals?

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '').split(/\./).slice(0, 2).join('.')" lang="en">
```

Comment: One reason why 'number' could be better than 'text' is on mobile, as that determines which keyboard is displayed.